# Netsuite Putting county on invoice and cash sales

Tags: javascript, netsuite

I need to add the county of the shipping zip code on all invoices and cash sales. This is so I can pull it for a report. I am new to coding so I am not sure what I need do. We do have existing code on the customer record that does it and add the lat and long on the record as well but I don't need that for this. Also pulling it from the customer record doesn't work because if for one order they change where it is shipped to it won't be updated. I made a free text form field with ID custbodysales_order_county.  Below is the code that is used on the customer record.

```
function getCounty(type){
try
{
    if(type=="addressbook")
    {
        //Find default shipping address in line item
        var zipCodeText //Variable to hold zip code
        var currentLine = nlapiGetCurrentLineItemIndex('addressbook')
        
        if (nlapiGetCurrentLineItemValue('addressbook', 'defaultshipping') == 'T' && nlapiGetCurrentLineItemValue('addressbook', 'zip') != null && nlapiGetCurrentLineItemValue('addressbook', 'zip') != "") {
            //Geocode default shipping address - added 6/1/2010 T.B.
            try {
                var shipAddress = nlapiGetCurrentLineItemValue("addressbook", "addr1", currentLine)
                shipAddress += ",+" + nlapiGetCurrentLineItemValue("addressbook", "city", currentLine) + ",+"
                shipAddress += nlapiGetCurrentLineItemValue("addressbook", "state", currentLine) + "+"
                shipAddress += nlapiGetCurrentLineItemValue("addressbook", "zip", currentLine)
                
                var geocodeXML = geocodeAddress(shipAddress) //<---Function in maps.js file
                var location = nlapiSelectNode(geocodeXML, "//*[name()='location']")
                var longitude = nlapiSelectValue(location, "//*[name()='lng']")
                var latitude = nlapiSelectValue(location, "//*[name()='lat']")
                var geocodeType = nlapiSelectValue(geocodeXML, "//*[name()='location_type']")
                nlapiSetFieldValue("custentity_longitude", longitude)
                nlapiSetFieldValue("custentity_latitude", latitude)
                nlapiSetFieldValue("custentity_geoaccuracy", geocodeType)
            } 
            catch (e) {
                //Do nothing - no error routine at present time
                //alert("Error geocoding address. Details: " + e.message)
            }
            
            //Retrieve the zip code of the default shipping address
            zipCodeText = nlapiGetCurrentLineItemValue('addressbook', 'zip')
        }
        
        var filters = [];
        filters.push(new nlobjSearchFilter("name", null, "is", zipCodeText));
        var cols = [];
        cols.push(new nlobjSearchColumn("custrecord_zip_code_map_state"));
        cols.push(new nlobjSearchColumn("custrecord_zip_code_map_county"));
        cols.push(new nlobjSearchColumn("custrecord_zip_code_map_sales_rep"));
        cols.push(new nlobjSearchColumn("custrecord_county_full_name", "custrecord_zip_code_map_county"));
        var results = nlapiSearchRecord("customrecord_zip_code_map", null, filters, cols);
        if (results) {
            nlapiSetFieldValue('custentity_county', results[0].getValue("custrecord_county_full_name", "custrecord_zip_code_map_county"));
            if (nlapiGetFieldValue("isperson") != "T") 
                nlapiSetFieldValue('salesrep', results[0].getValue("custrecord_zip_code_map_sales_rep"));
        }
        else {
            if (nlapiGetFieldValue("isperson") != "T") 
                nlapiSetFieldValue('salesrep', '8732');
        }
    }
    
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*Also pulling it from the customer record doesn't work because if for one order they change where it is shipped to it won't be updated.*

This indicates the county should be included as a part of the address.  You can add a custom field to the address record using the following steps:

1. Navigate to Customization > Forms > Address Forms.
2. Edit the relevant address form.  If there are no custom address forms in your account, you will have to Customize the standard form instead.
3. Click the New Field button.
4. Fill the required fields to create your new field to hold the County names and Save.
5. Back on the Custom Address Entry Form, edit the Address Template field to add the county field you created in the appropriate place.  For instance, you could change `<CITY> <STATE> <ZIP>` to `<CITY> <CUSTRECORD_COUNTY> <STATE> <ZIP>`

Now once you update the addresses they will display with the county anywhere the address is used in future.  For existing transactions, you may have to update them.

Comment: I was hoping to make it more automated on the records because we do sell on amazon and our website. They don't auto populate the county with the code above. I did try your suggestion and I couldn't find the county field under the address under report.